# How do I implement a min heap from a max heap?

Tags: c++, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

I have a heap sorted by max values, I want to have a function where I can use min values instead to on top. I can either convert the max heap to a min, or create a min heap altogether. Which one would be easier ?

Here is my Heap.cpp

```
// *********************************************************
// Implementation file Heap.cpp for the ADT heap.
// *********************************************************
#include "Heap.h"  // header file for heap

heapClass::heapClass() : Size(0)
{
}  // end default constructor

bool heapClass::HeapIsEmpty() const
{
return bool(Size == 0);
}  // end HeapIsEmpty

void heapClass::HeapInsert(const heapItemType& NewItem,
                       bool& Success)
// Method: Inserts the new item after the last item in the
// heap and trickles it up to its proper position. The
// heap is full when it contains MAX_HEAP items.
{
Success = bool(Size < MAX_HEAP);

if (Success)
{  // place the new item at the end of the heap
    Items[Size] = NewItem;

    // trickle new item up to its proper position
    int Place = Size;
    int Parent = (Place - 1)/2;
    while ( (Parent >= 0) &&
           (Items[Place].Key() > Items[Parent].Key()) )
    {  // swap Items[Place] and Items[Parent]
        heapItemType Temp = Items[Parent];
        Items[Parent] = Items[Place];
        Items[Place] = Temp;

        Place = Parent;
        Parent = (Place -1 )/2;
    }  // end while

    ++Size;
}  // end if
}  // end HeapInsert

void heapClass::HeapDelete(heapItemType& RootItem,
                       bool& Success)
// Method: Swaps the last item in the heap with the root
// and trickles it down to its proper position.
{
Success = bool(!HeapIsEmpty());

if (Success)
{  RootItem = Items[0];
    Items[0] = Items[--Size];
    RebuildHeap(0);
}  // end if
}  // end HeapDelete

void heapClass::RebuildHeap(int Root)
{
// if the root is not a leaf and the root's search key
// is less than the larger of the search keys in the
// root's children
int Child = 2 * Root + 1;  // index of root's left
// child, if any
if ( Child < Size )
{  // root is not a leaf, so it has a left child at Child
    int RightChild = Child + 1;  // index of right child,
    // if any

    // if root has a right child, find larger child
    if ( (RightChild < Size) &&
        (Items[RightChild].Key() > Items[Child].Key()) )
        Child = RightChild;  // index of larger child

    // if the root's value is smaller than the
    // value in the larger child, swap values
    if ( Items[Root].Key() < Items[Child].Key() )
    {  heapItemType Temp = Items[Root];
        Items[Root] = Items[Child];
        Items[Child] = Temp;

        // transform the new subtree into a heap
        RebuildHeap(Child);
    }  // end if
   }  // end if

// if root is a leaf, do nothing
}  // end RebuildHeap
```

Heap.h

```
 // *********************************************************
 // Header file Heap.h for the ADT heap.
// *********************************************************

#include "Data.h"  // definition of itemClass
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h"

#pragma once

const int MAX_HEAP = 20;
typedef itemClass keyType;

typedef itemClass heapItemType;

class heapClass
{
public:
heapClass();  // default constructor
// copy constructor and destructor are
// supplied by the compiler

// heap operations:
virtual bool HeapIsEmpty() const;
// Determines whether a heap is empty.
// Precondition: None.
// Postcondition: Returns true if the heap is empty;
// otherwise returns false.

virtual void HeapInsert(const heapItemType& NewItem,
                        bool& Success);
// Inserts an item into a heap.
// Precondition: NewItem is the item to be inserted.
// Postcondition: If the heap was not full, NewItem is
// in its proper position and Success is true;
// otherwise Success is false.

virtual void HeapDelete(heapItemType& RootItem,
                        bool& Success);
// Retrieves and deletes the item in the root of a heap.
// This item has the largest search key in the heap.
// Precondition: None.
// Postcondition: If the heap was not empty, RootItem
// is the retrieved item, the item is deleted from the
// heap, and Success is true. However, if the heap was
// empty, removal is impossible and Success is false.

protected:
void RebuildHeap(int Root);
// Converts the semiheap rooted at index Root
// into a heap.

private:
heapItemType Items[MAX_HEAP];  // array of heap items
int          Size;             // number of heap items
};  // end class
// End of header file.
```

Snippet containing itemClass

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "Data.h"

/* Put in definitions of methods declared in Data.h
 - modify as you wish. */

/*  ==================================================
 Default constructor
 ================================================== */
itemClass::itemClass() : trackRequest(-100),
serialNum(-1)
{
}

/*  ==================================================
 Constructor
 ================================================== */
itemClass::itemClass(int trkR, int srlNum, bool dir)
: trackRequest(trkR),
 serialNum (srlNum),direction(dir)
{
}

   /*  ==================================================
  Key
  ================================================== */
/* This method returns the search key.
 Here we assume the key is the item itself. */

itemClass itemClass::Key() const
{
return *this ;
}

/*  ==================================================
 Equality Test
 ================================================== */
bool itemClass::operator== (const itemClass& Rhs) const
{
return (trackRequest == Rhs.trackRequest)
&& (serialNum == Rhs.serialNum) && (direction== Rhs.direction);
}

/*  ==================================================
 non-Equality Test
 ================================================== */
bool itemClass::operator!= (const itemClass& Rhs) const
{
return !(*this==Rhs) ;
}

 /*  ==================================================
 Less-Than Test
 ================================================== */
bool itemClass::operator< (const itemClass& Rhs) const
{

   return(trackRequest < Rhs.trackRequest) && (direction      <=Rhs.direction);
//return true;
 }

/*  ==================================================
 Less-Than-Or-Equal Test
 ================================================== */
bool itemClass::operator<= (const itemClass& Rhs) const
{
return (*this<Rhs) || (*this==Rhs) ;
}

 /*  ==================================================
 Greater-Than Test
 ================================================== */
bool itemClass::operator> (const itemClass& Rhs) const
{
return (!(*this<Rhs) && !(*this==Rhs)) ;
/* OR return (Rhs<*this); */
}

/*  ==================================================
 Greater-Than-Or-Equal Test
 ================================================== */
bool itemClass::operator>= (const itemClass& Rhs) const
{
return ( !(*this<Rhs) ) ;
}
```

Comment: What is `itemClass`?

Comment: @templatetypedef the data i am inserting I didnt include it because I thought it would be too much code.

Comment: you can use templates or constructor to initialize a heap with a comparator function and use that comparator in your code instead of > which will make you code work for both cases

Comment: @m7mdbadawy for example I have my comparators declared in my Data file.

Comment: @Mikejones you need something like std::greater<itemClass>() and use it for each comparison and replace it with std::less to get min heap

Comment: @m7mdbadawy would that be used with a template? and would be added to my heap file? sorry I am not that familiar with the use of a template